# Android ListView losing data when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapter, baseadapter

I am using ListView to show TextViews in some rows and not others. I don't know how many items there will be, it runs fine but when I scroll down the display changed.

I'm working on an app where users fill reports and polls. In an activity I have a ListView where children contain EditTexts, Checkbox and TextView.

The problem with EditTexts and Checkbox was that when scrolling, the content that they have is lost. I was able to fix the Checkbox problem by saving the check status in an array, but I can't fix the problem with EditTexts. I know that there are some questions about this particular issue but the solutions that they provided doesn't seem to work.

Im using this BaseAdapter.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
private ModelTable avModelTable = new ModelTable();
private BrandTable brandTable = new BrandTable();

public ProductAdapter(Context mContext, List<Model> models) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.models = models;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return models.size();
}

@Override
public Model getItem(int i) {
    return models.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}


@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ProductHolder item = new ProductHolder();
    View row = view;
    if (row == null) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item, viewGroup, false);

        item.nameProduct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nameProduct);
        item.subCategoryProduct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.subCategoryProduct);
        item.productGroup = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.groupRadioProduct);
        item.oos_product = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.oos_product);
        item.av_product = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.av_product);
        item.shelfProduct = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.shelfProduct);
        item.quantityProduct = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantityProduct);
        item.priceProduct = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.priceProduct);
        item.layoutBrand = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.layoutBrand);
        item.avBrand = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.avBrand);


        row.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (ProductHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    final Model model = models.get(i);

    item.nameProduct.setText(model.getProduct_name());
    item.subCategoryProduct.setText(brandTable.getBrandName(model.getBrand_id()));

    if (model.getQuantity() != 0) {
        item.quantityProduct.setText(String.valueOf(model.getQuantity()));
    }
    if (model.getShelf() != 0) {
        item.shelfProduct.setText(String.valueOf(model.getShelf()));
    }

    if (model.getPrice() != null) {
        item.priceProduct.setText(model.getPrice());
    }

    if (model.getBrand_id() == 1) {

        item.layoutBrand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        item.avBrand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        item.productGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        item.oos_product.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        item.av_product.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        switch (model.getAv()) {
            case 0:
                item.oos_product.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case 1:
                item.av_product.setChecked(true);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        item.productGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.oos_product:
                        avModelTable.updateAv(model.getId(), 0);
                        break;
                    case R.id.av_product:
                        avModelTable.updateAv(model.getId(), 1);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

        });


    } else {


        item.layoutBrand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        item.avBrand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        item.productGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        item.oos_product.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        item.av_product.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        item.avBrand.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg0.toString().equals("")) {
                    avModelTable.updateAv(model.getId(), 0);
                } else avModelTable.updateAv(model.getId(), Integer.parseInt(arg0.toString()));

            }
        });

    }


    item.shelfProduct.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg0.toString().equals("")) {
                avModelTable.updateShelf(model.getId(), 0);
            } else avModelTable.updateShelf(model.getId(), Integer.parseInt(arg0.toString()));

        }
    });

    item.quantityProduct.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg0.toString().equals("")) {
                avModelTable.updateQuantity(model.getId(), 0);
            } else
                avModelTable.updateQuantity(model.getId(), Integer.parseInt(arg0.toString()));

        }
    });

    item.priceProduct.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg0.toString().equals("")) {
                avModelTable.updatePrice(model.getId(), null);
            } else
                avModelTable.updatePrice(model.getId(), arg0.toString());

        }
    });


    return row;
}


private class ProductHolder {
    private TextView nameProduct, subCategoryProduct;
    private RadioButton oos_product, av_product;
    private RadioGroup productGroup;
    private EditText shelfProduct, quantityProduct, priceProduct, avBrand;
    private LinearLayout layoutBrand;

}
```

}

Comment: did you get any solutions for it ??? I'm been having the same problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

I made a test code using your adapter but with different views/models and tried it but it didn't work. It only worked after I replaced `View row = view`; with `View row = null;` at the start of your `getView` method, forcing the code to inflate the views every time. That's why I believe the problem is at the `item = (ProductHolder) row.getTag();` part. Perhaps the `ProductHolder` model is not correct.